How to check current Jetpack Compose destination in a type-safe manner?
Since version 2.8.0 of the library androidx.navigation:navigation-compose we have a new type-safe navigation API available. I am trying to use it in my app but I have this problem.
My app has a NavigationBar which has multiple destinations:
NavigationBar {
        BottomBarDestination.entries.forEach {
            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = ?????,
                label = { Text(text = it.title) },
                onClick = {/*TODO change destination*/},
                icon = { Icon(imageVector = it.icon, contentDescription = it.title) }
            )
        }
    }

When I change the destination, I need to update the selected property of each navigation item. However, I haven't found any type-safe solution that works. How can I check the current destination if it matches the destination of the NavigationItem? I know I can store a simple String inside the NavigationItem and compare it to the route but I don't find that very type-safe. I want to leverage the type-safe API.

It feels like you should be observing state that gets updated by your nav host logic, or perhaps instead passing in a parameter to this composable from that nav host logic.

What would you have written there in the non type safe APIs? Please include that code.

@ianhanniballake before, I had it like this: selected = backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route == it.navDestination::class.qualifiedName. I'd say recipe for disaster. The answer from Adnan Habib is exactly the thing I was looking for.

Next time, include that code in your question, as requested almost a week ago.

@ianhanniballake will do, thank you.

There's a hasRoute() extension method on NavDestination specifically for this case.
val items = listOf(Profile, Dashboard())

NavigationBar {
    val navBackStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    items.forEach { destination ->
        NavigationBarItem(
            selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any {
                it.hasRoute(destination::class)
            } == true,
            // ...
        )
    }
}

Here’s a demo app showcasing Type Safe Navigation in Jetpack Compose with a Bottom Navigation Bar:
https://github.com/AdnanHabibMirza/Type_Safe_Navigation_Compose

Came back to this post to write the answer but found yours. Thanks.
I was struggling with this as well and found the solution over the kotlin slack channel, so thought to write an answer here.

This is indeed the perfect answer I was looking for. Some fancy extension method that gets the job done. Thanks!

This doesn't work. When you have nested navigation in each tab the hasRoute method return false for parent navigation even if they should match the destination.
